# draw lines from a given point to all points in a file in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw lines from origin `(0,0)` to all points whose coordinates are given in a file, using `gnuplot`. For e.g. if the file contains data as:

```
1,1
1,2
```

Then I want a straight lines from `(0,0) to (1,1)` and `(0,0) to (1,2)`. Since I have a lot of points, I can't do it manually for each point in the file. How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to accomplish this would be to plot using vectors, but setting the origin as `(0,0)` for all points, then removing the vector heads:

```
plot "datafile" using (0):(0):1:2 with vectors
```

which results in:

[image]

More info [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node259.html). by the way, if your input files looks exactly like the one you posted:

```
1,1
1,2
```

You'll need to add `set datafile separator ','` before plotting. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to use a `plot for` loop over the block index. If you insert two white lines between the coordinates in your file, they are viewed as different blocks, so that you can write

```
plot for [j=0:N] 'data.dat' index j u 1:2 with lines
```

where N is the number of points. However, in this way you need to add the point of the origin in your file in each block, i.e. in the form

```
#your data file
0 0
1 1


0 0
1 2
```

I don't know how many points you have or if you have to perform this on many files. With few points you could modify the file by hand, otherwise I will suggest preparing a script (in `bash` for example with `sed` or others...).